# How to restrict user from accessing a page by typing a url using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to restrict user accessing a page by typing a url using react and typescript.

when the user clicks view button it redirects him to "/view" and displays View component.

Now this view button is displayed for admin only and clicking this view button would redirect him to "/view" which renders View component.

Below is the code,

```
function Main() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Switch>
                <Route>
                    //some route logic
                </Route>
                <Route 
                    path="/view"
                    render={routeProps => (
                        <Layout>
                            <View {...routeProps} />
                        </Layout>
                    )}
                />
            </Switch>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}


function ChildComponent () { //this is where the view button is rendered
    const admin = //http request to get this value and is boolean;
    return (
        <> 
            {admin ? (
                <a href="/view">
                    <button>view</button>
                </a>) : (

        </>
    );
}

function View() { //this is view component rendered in "/view" url
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div>title</div>
            <div>view content</div>
        </Wrapper>
    );
 }
```

the above code works...but i want to solve the cases below,

```
nonadmin users when they type "/view" url they can still get to "/view" page where View component is 
rendered.

Also a scenario where admin user is in "/view" url and in this page user is changed to nonadmin then 
he is still in "/view" page. he should get back to "/" url.

And when user is nonadmin and is in page say "/item/id" then typing "/view" should redirect him or 
keep him in the same page.
```

To achieve above cases i have tried something like below, within View component i check for user being admin or not and route him to "/" url.

```
function Output () {
    return (
         <Wrapper>
            <div>title</div>
            <div>view content</div>
        </Wrapper
    );
}

function View() { //this is view component rendered in "/view" url
    cosnt admin = //got by http request and the value is boolean;
    return (
        <Route path="/view">
            {admin ? <Output /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </Route>
    );
 }
```

the above code works but not completely meaning works for cases below,

when nonadmin users types url "/view" then it will redirect him to "/" page. but instead of always redirecting always to "/" url should get him to page where he is currently in.

when admin user is in "/view" and in this page if user is changed to nonadmin then nonadmin user is still in "/view" page unless a page refresh.

How can i solve the above cases. I am new to using react route and redirects and i am not sure how to use them.

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a check before rendering your `view` page.

```
render() {
    if(!user.isAdmin) {
       if(fromScreen) {
          fallTo(fromScreen);
          return;
       } else {
          fallTo("/");
          return;
       }
     }
  return (<> {this.renderViewBody()} </>);
}
```

the fromScreen and the user permissions must be available as props.